# How to get Phalcon to delegate actions to other controllers?

Tags: php, phalcon, event-loop

## The problem

I would like to be able to write controller-like classes and provide them as a vendor to the end applications. Then the end application controller could just instantiate my class and invoke their action methods.

The thing is that I want them to be invoked automatically. I must avoid repeating each action method in the end controller.

## First approach

I've tried this:

#### Code

```
class IndexController
{
    protected $vendorController;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->vendorController = new VendorController();
    }

    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        call_user_func_args([$this->vendorController, $name], $args);
    }
}
```

where the `VendorController` class looks like this:

```
class VendorController 
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        die("this is test action");
    }
}
```

#### Result

but it gives me

```
Action 'test' was not found on handler 'index'
```

<s>I'm assuming</s> [I've checked](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/c8d4916bbfd0cb18395fe25d8c5a663fc5077d8f/phalcon/dispatcher.zep#L431) that Phalcon internally does some checking which looks like this:

```
if (method_exists($controller, $actionName)) { // ...
```

which results in not found action.

Perhaps I can override this behavior somehow? I'm using my own dispatcher class that extends Phalcon's native dispatcher if that helps in any way. But I've tried to override methods like `getHandlerName()` without any success.

## Second approach

I also tried to use traits:

#### Code

```
trait TVendorController
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        die("this is test action");
    }
}

class IndexController
{
    use TVendorController;
}
```

And this approach works, but has a major flaw:

#### The flaw

If the `IndexController` extends some kind of `BaseController` that contains methods like `initialize()` or `beforeExecuteRoute()` (which is often the case) then it is too easy to forget about calling them. The threat here is that `BaseController` methods can contain for example authentication logic:

```
trait TVendorController
{
    public function beforeExecuteRoute()
    {
        // silently overrides the BaseController::beforeExecuteRoute()
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        die("this is test action");
    }
}


abstract class BaseController
{
    public function beforeExecuteRoute()
    {
        // OOPS: this is never called
        $username = $this->session->get('username', null);
        if (!$username) {
            $this->response->redirect('index/login');
        }
    }
}


class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    use TVendorController;
}
```

## The questions

In case of the first approach: how to tell Phalcon's event-loop that the action actually exists in controller?

Or if it cannot be done then:

1. How to write my vendor controllers?
2. How to combine them into end application controllers so that actions will get called automatically?

Comment: You should think about Service approach

Comment: @Robert would you point me to some resource where I can start?

Comment: Sure -> https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/di.html

Comment: @Robert I was hoping for something more specific... That link I actually googled in the meantime.

Comment: It's all about DI and Service Locators there are a lot of such articles. This link is framework specific but Pattern is the same.

Comment: @Robert I just don't see how Phalcon's DI will help in my case. I never heard of anything that would use DI to locate controllers. This is a job for Router, not for Service Locator.

Comment: Maybe using inheritance ? Making the end user extend your controller ?

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos: This would deny end controllers the ability of inheriting any generic controllers from the app itself. I.e. it would prevent users of my vendor library from implementing functionality described in the second approach above.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to add EventManager with `dispatch:beforeDispatch` attachment. At `dispatch:beforeDispatch` moment you know action name but it should be possible to hit it before checking if action does actually exists.

In `beforeDispatch` function you may want to check, if delivered action name is callable inside controller, and if not, you should be able to forward to some king of `execvendorAction` method.

#### EDIT:

I have done this event managing:

```
$di->setShared('dispatcher', function() {

    $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

    $eventsManager = new EventsManager();

    $eventsManager->attach("dispatch:beforeDispatch", function($event, $dispatcher) {

        $controllerName = $dispatcher->getControllerClass();
        $action = $dispatcher->getActionName();

        if(!method_exists($controllerName, $action . 'Action')) {

            $dispatcher->forward(array(
                // not delivering 'controller' param to make it stay
                // in current one
                'action' => 'vendor',
                'params' => array(
                    'name' => $action,
                    'params' => $dispatcher->getParams()
                )
            ));
        }
    });

    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
    return $dispatcher;
});
```

Than, I've added in `controllerBase` such an action:

```
public function vendorAction($name, $arguments) {

    var_dump(array(
        'name' => $name,
        'arguments' => $arguments
    ));

    // $name .= 'Action';
    if(method_exists(array($this->vendorController, $name))) {
        call_user_func_args(array($this->vendorController, $name), $arguments);
    } else {
         // work it out
    }
}
```

and got it working. Every controller extending from `controllerBase` will run your methods in delivered in it `vendorController`. You will have to work out your own way to handle `notFound` exceptions, as this is a very nonstandard implementation.

Tested with classic router/dispatcher/everything on Phalcon.

Comment: Thanks man, it was a good idea but unfortunately it doesn't work. I [looked it up in source](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/c8d4916bbfd0cb18395fe25d8c5a663fc5077d8f/phalcon/dispatcher.zep#L364) and turns out that the handler is determined before any events are fired, so I don't have any control over which controller is used. But you gave me an idea that i can overload the `dispatch()` method.

Comment: @MaciejSz can't agree, it should work. Have extended my answer, check it out. I powodzenia ;)

Comment: Ohh now it makes more sense! I was missing the trick with `vendorAction()` method. That's kinda cool :) I'll try to implement this and get back to you. The `notFound` should not be a problem, but I see that I still have to resolve a problem with calling methods like `initialize()` and `beforeExecuteRoute()` on the `$this->vendorController` object.